# How to dynamically render list of fontawesome icons in react that shows error "Could not find icon {prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'faChartLine'"

Tags: reactjs, list, icons, react-link, font-awesome-6

I have a list route with fontAwesome icon declared in it link this -

```
const navigationList = [
    {
      pageName: "Dashboard",
      path: "/",
      iconName: `faChartLine`
    },
    {
      pageName: "Bus Information",
      path: "/bus-info",
      iconName: `faBus`
    },
    {
      pageName: "Organization Chart",
      path: "/org-chart",
      iconName: `faSitemap`
    }
  ]
```

Then, I loop through the array and place it in the **Link** like this -

```
{
  navigationList.map((link, index) => {
   return (
      <Link
       to={link.path}
       key={index}
       className={`text-2xl text-gray-500 font-bold p-2`}
      >
       <FontAwesomeIcon icon={link.iconName} className={"mr-4"}></FontAwesomeIcon>{link.pageName}
     </Link>
  )
})
}
```

I see no error in terms of writing the code. But, somehow it shows me
**index.es.js:278 Could not find icon {prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'faChartLine'}**

I tried console log the list and the iconName appears in the console with no error.

Please need your help here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem comes from adding the **Individual Icons Explicitly** which doesn't work with rendering icons dynamically.

I look through again in [fontawesome doc, Add Icons Globally](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons#add-icons-globally) section and found the answer.

- import library and fas from fontawesome.
- add the icons you want to use into the library with add() method like this - library.add(fas, faTwitter, faFontAwesome, faHatCowboy, faHatChef)
- use the icon name without **fa** in front of it.
- use syntax like this in fontawesome component -> icon={["fas", "icon-name"]}

This solved my case.